# Donde tengo el error [c++ functions]

Tags: c++, array, funciones

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int sumAll(int nums[5]){
    int result;
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        result += nums[i];
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){

    int superarray[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    cout << "Resultado: " << sumAll(superarray) << endl;

}
```

El código tiene un output dinámico, y no se que hace por detrás ya que me da valores muy grandes.

**Output 1**

```
Resultado: 32779
```

Si vuelvo a ejecutar el programa de me imprime otro resultado

**Output 2**

```
Resultado: 32781
```

Me gustaría saber por que pasa esto, y como hacer que me devuelva la suma de los elementos del array que le pase a la función.

Comment: La variable `result` no está inicializada por lo que contendra basura y tu le estás sumando a esa basura, de ahí que te de un resultado diferente cada vez y que sea muy grande, solo haz `int result = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo basta iniciar result con valor 0.

No has hecho eso.

---

Con respecto a por que sucede, es debido a que en C++ las variables pueden ser inicializadas con valor indeterminado

Probablemente en tu caso, haya sido así. Si no es así, alguien seguro me corrige.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int sumAll(int nums[5]){
    int result = 0;
    cout << "Valor inicial: " << result << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        result += nums[i];
        cout << result << endl;
    }
    cout << "Resultado:";
    return result;
}

int main(){
    int superarray[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    cout << sumAll(superarray) << endl;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, lo he solucionado. Y porque me devolvía valores tan grandes? De donde los sacaba? Ahora tengo curiosidad.

Comment: @z3r0 al no ser inicializado `result`, se convertiría en un valor indeterminado, retornando valores grandes o pequeños, ya que éstos valores indeterminados devuelven resultados aleatorios sin ningún patrón existente.